# Disable postfix from emailing sender

Tags: postfix

We email customers their voicemails from no-reply@our-domain.com. I see that Postfix is trying to send out a lot of emails to no-reply@our-domain.com. I assume this is either delivery reports or because the email that we are sending is being rejected and PostFix is trying to notify the sender. On the voicemail server I have set in /etc/aliases

```
no-reply: /dev/null
```

however this is not working. I suspect this is because the machine name is mail1.location.our-domain.com so it tries to send it to the MX record for our-domain.com. How do I configure post fix to a. disable delivery reports and b. /dev/null all bounce back emails.

Comment: Here you can find answer: https://serverfault.com/q/638152/293588

Comment: That clears the queue. I want Postfix to just not send the emails and drops them on its own.

Answer (score 1):

An example of how I do exactly this for no-reply. In `main.cf`:

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport_maps
```

Inside the transport_maps file:

```
no-reply@domain.com discard
```

`postmap transport_maps` to generate the transport_maps.db

Any mail to that address disappears to a black hole.

Comment: Worked perfectly. TY.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve that is use postfix *header_checks* functionnality to match outgoing e-mails containing "no-reply" as destination.
the documentation is available here: [header_checks(5) - Postfix manual](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html)

Here is an example I personally use in production to hold such e-mails:

```
/^[T|t][O|o]:\s+noreply@.+/  HOLD noreply_adress
```

Just make sure your postfix *header_checks* parameter points to the correct file, for example here:

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```